# Grabbing models from database in asynchronous function (Channel Consumer) Django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-channels

## Summary

Hello, currently I am working on a application that sends data to the frontend in Realtime through using django-channels. I have been able to do this for all models that are created when they page is opened, however I have not yet been able to grab previous models for when the page has not been opened yet.

### Code

Below was one of my first attempts at getting this system working, this would be called when the consumer connect method would be fired, and after the connection was accepted I would run this for loop

```py
for app in Application.objects.all():
    app_json = ApplicationSerializer(app).data
    await self.send_json({'action': 'create', 'data': app_json})
```

When running this code I would get the error message of
`django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.`

This makes sense since the consumers connect method is asynchronous, so following the advice of the message I went ahead and used `sync_to_async`

```py
for app in sync_to_async(Application.objects.all)():
    app_json = ApplicationSerializer(app).data
    await self.send_json({'action': 'create', 'data': app_json})
```

I decided to use `sync_to_async` around the Application objects since the error message highlighted the for loop line itself and also I know that the applicationSerializer would be working correctly since I have used it in other async methods just fine

This results in `TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable`

#### Final Thoughts

I am new to both django-channels and asynchronous, if I knew that channels was going to be heavily based on asynchronous I would have studied the system before I started this project.

I have looked on other stack overflow posts and saw that potentially mapping the data might be a solution but I am not 100% sure if this is a asynchronous problem or with django-channels

What are some other things I can try?

#### Update

Based off of Kens suggestion I went ahead and tried the following code:

```py
   apps = await database_sync_to_async(Application.objects.all)()
   for app in apps:
       app_json = ApplicationSerializer(app).data
       print(app_json)
```

This returned the stacktrace

```
Exception inside application: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 254, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\auth.py", line 181, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 150, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 94, in app
    return await consumer(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 58, in __call__
    await await_many_dispatch(
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
    await handler(message)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 196, in websocket_receive
    await self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 259, in receive
    await self.receive_json(await self.decode_json(text_data), **kwargs)
  File "D:\HomeAutomation\HomeAutomation\consumers.py", line 28, in receive_json
    for app in apps:
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 287, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1154, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Devin\.virtualenvs\HomeAutomation-l9uhKhE0\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code `sync_to_async(Application.objects.all)()` creates a coroutine which needs to be awaited and not used directly. For your specific case, it would be better to first get the data outside the for loop and then proceed. Also, you may want to use `database_sync_to_async` instead.

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

apps = await database_sync_to_async(Application.objects.all)()
for app in apps:
    app_json = ApplicationSerializer(app).data
    await self.send_json({'action': 'create', 'data': app_json})
```

As a side note, ensure that there will be no database queries when the serializer serialized the app instance. To do so, use `select_related` and `prefetch_related` to prefetch any nested objects that may be needed

**UPDATE**: Yes, due to the lazy nature of some Django ORM methods like `.all()`, the database won't actually be hit at the point of calling the method but at the point when it is being used. A common way to force it to execute immediately, is to convert the queryset to a list.
Try this:

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

apps = await database_sync_to_async(list)(Application.objects.all())
for app in apps:
    app_json = ApplicationSerializer(app).data
    await self.send_json({'action': 'create', 'data': app_json})
```

Comment: Hello, I went ahead and tried what you suggested and interestingly I got the same error

`django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.`

There error this time is raised on when we declare `apps`

Comment: @Timberghost_ post the full stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I went ahead and updated the post with the stacktrace

Comment: @Timberghost_ yeah, my bad. Check my edit

Comment: Yup did the trick! just out of curiosity how did you know that a list was needed to wrap the data in? could you tell you needed to do this from the stacktrace?

Anyhow, thanks for all the work you put into this problem greatly appreciated!

Comment: am glad I could be of help. It doesn't have to be a list specifically but that is what is commonly used because a list is similar to queryset and you can still loop through it. For performance and probably other reasons, Django does not execute the query it gets to a point where the objects are needed. To convert the queryset to a Python list, it needs to load the data from DB, hence executing the query. You can read it up about it in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy.